# Ansible playbook to access Git repo

Tags: git, ansible

I have a playbook as shown below:

```
---
- hosts: 172.xx.xx.xx
remote_user: ec2-user
become: yes
become_method: sudo
tasks:
- git:
repo: https://github.com/mygitrepo/falconow.git
dest: /var/www/html
version: release-0.1
```

When I try to run this playbook I am getting an error as shown below:

```
    fatal: [172.xx.xx.xx]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failed": true, "msg": "Failed to find required executable git"}
 [WARNING]: Could not create retry file
'/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Ansible/copy.retry'.         [Errno 13] Permission
denied: u'/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Ansible/copy.retry'
```

I am sure about the existence of such repo or files in it. Can someone point me in right direction please.

Comment: Ansible is already pointing you in the right direction: `Failed to find required executable git`.

Comment: he he.. I understand that.. But what does that mean? I googled and tried few results, but not working.

Comment: I think a good idea is to install `git` on server `172.xx.xx.xx`...

Comment: on server 172..? This server is a node, basically a simulation of web server, where I try to fetch the files from git and place it in the directory. In that case, do we need to install git on all the machines we access with this playbook..?

Or do you mean to say to install git in Ansible server?

Comment: Ansible executes tasks on remote servers. So, yes, all requirements for modules must be installed on remote servers.

Comment: Great, looks like you're an Ansible pro.. Thank u so much. I would be happy to accept if you post this as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer from comment:

> I think a good idea is to install `git` on server `172.xx.xx.xx`...
>
> Ansible executes tasks on remote servers. So, yes, all requirements for modules must be installed on remote servers.